# Changing order of display names from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a site which displays name for a logged in user. I want to display the newly added name first on the page. For e.g. After I posted this question on stackoverflow my name would have been displayed first on the homepage.

I have a form that accepts the name and a display.php to display the name is:

```
<?php

  mysql_connect('mysql', 'Usere', 'Pass');
  mysql_select_db('a5803761_add');
  $query =mysql_query('select * from addname');

  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
  {
    echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;">''<a href='.$row['url'].>'.$row['name'].'</a>''</div>';
  }

?>
```

This shows the name like:

```
Mark                james             Bond   
bill                gates
```

Now, when I add stack name to my database it displays like this:

```
Mark                james              Bond   
bill                gates              stack
```

but I want to display stack first like this:

```
stack               Mark              james   
bond                bill              gates
```

Just assume 010000000 names are there on my database and I want to display the latest added names first on the webpage

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC` -> and for the next time, try to be relevant (those spaces are not relevant to the question, but your database structure _is_)

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Try This Code

```
<?php

mysql_connect('mysql', 'Usere', 'Pass');
mysql_select_db('a5803761_add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addname order by ID DESC limit 1');


while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo '<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;"><a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></div>';
}

?>
```

This must work for you

Comment: Means i save data of what ever users did when he was logged inn

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this work for you...

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
   {
        $name1=  $row['name'];
        $url1=  $row['url'];        
    }
<div style="min-width:300px;height:100px;border:red 5px;float:left;"><a href="<?php echo $url1; ?>"><?php echo $name1; ?></a></div>
```